# Remove blank elements/spaces from beautifulsoup parsing

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I parse with beautifulsoup html tags from a html page and get the text content from this tags.

Somehow empty/blank lines are in my output, and I cannot find this reason of this.
Then I tried to format the output with PrettyTable. Looks quite well, but brings me nothing. Because I want to import the file later in MS Access. It can be .csv to as output.

I hope you can help me.

Part of my Code:

```
    text_file = open("Output3.txt", "w")
    table = PrettyTable(['Names', 'Addresses'])

    with urllib.request.urlopen("file:///C:/Users/x/Desktop/test.html") as url:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "html.parser")

        names = [name.get_text() for name in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "name m08_name"})]
        addresses = [address.get_text() for address in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "adresse m08_adresse"})]
        for line in zip(names, addresses):
            table.add_row(line)

        text_file.write(str(table))
        text_file.close()
        print("Prozess finish")
```

My current output:

The output is coming from a open source phone book. The adresses are doctors in the city. Its no privat data and information.

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|                                                          Namen                                                          |            Adressen           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                        Augenarzt Dr.med. Wolf Eckard Weingärtner                                        |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |          Königstr. 70         |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |     70173 Stuttgart-Mitte     |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                   Baumann Achim Dr. med., Facharzt für Hautkrankheiten                                  |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |          Königstr. 66         |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |     70173 Stuttgart-Mitte     |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                         Ärztehaus am Diakonie-Klinikum Praxis für Mund-, Kiefer- und Plastische                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |         Falkertstr. 46        |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |      70176 Stuttgart-West     |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                     Ihr Hautarzt Dr. Malte-Christian Thode, Dr. Sabrina Germann-Samara und Kollegen                     |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |         Wilhelmstr. 40        |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |    71638 Ludwigsburg-Mitte    |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|               Ärztehaus-West Dr.med.Angela Faller, Dr.med. Claudia Lerschmacher Faller, Lerschmacher, Vogt              |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |        Kornbergstr. 29        |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |      70176 Stuttgart-West     |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                 Richter Constanze Dr.med., Fachärztin für Innere Medizin                                |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |        Seelbergstr. 11        |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         | 70372 Stuttgart-Bad Cannstatt |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                               Dr.med. Ulrich Schreiber, Ihre Frauenarztpraxis in Stuttgart                              |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |         Hirschstr. 31         |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |     70173 Stuttgart-Mitte     |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                             Günther Eck Dr.med., FA für HNO                                             |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |          Marienstr. 5         |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |     70178 Stuttgart-Mitte     |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                      Ambulante Gastroenterologie Dres.med. Karl M. Teubner, Albrecht G. Maier, Diet                     |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |        Industriestr. 4        |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |   70565 Stuttgart-Vaihingen   |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                          Bergener Malte Dr.med., Reuter Matthias Dr.med., Ungemach Gerd Dr.med.                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |        Wilhelmsplatz 11       |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |     70182 Stuttgart-Mitte     |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                 Dr. med. Holger Lange Facharzt für Urologie - Belegarzt                                 |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |         Hirschstr. 31         |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |     70173 Stuttgart-Mitte     |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                        Abel Theophil Dr.med., Arzt für Orthopädie                                       |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |         Schwabstr. 91         |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |      70193 Stuttgart-West     |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
| Ambulante Pneumologie mit Allergiezentrum (BAG) - Dr.med.Frank Heimann Dr.med.Rainer Ehmann, Dr.med.K. Seyfahrt-Jürgens |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |        Rotebühlplatz 19       |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |     70178 Stuttgart-Mitte     |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                         Aerzte am HautTherapieZentrum Stuttgart                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |         Calwer Str. 11        |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |     70173 Stuttgart-Mitte     |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                            auge im fokus Dr.med. Pervanidis, Dr.med. Wagner, Dr.med. Stergiou                           |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |        Rotebühlplatz 17       |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |     70178 Stuttgart-Mitte     |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
|                                                                                                                         |                               |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

My expected output:

```
names; adresses;

name1; adress1
name2; adress2
..  ; ..
```

Short snipped from the test.html

```
<div class="adresse m08_adresse" data-role="adresse" itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/PostalAddress">
    <address>
        <a
                href="https://adresse.gelbeseiten.de/1124105191531/baumann-achim-dr-med-facharzt-fuer-hautkrankheiten/stuttgart/mitte#originIndex=1;origin=/arzt/stuttgart"
                data-wipe='{"listener":"click","name":"Trefferliste Adresse zur Detailseite","id":"1124105191531", "synchron": true}'


            >
        <span itemprop="streetAddress">Königstr.&nbsp;66</span>
            <br />
        <span itemprop="postalCode">70173</span>&nbsp;<span itemprop="addressLocality">Stuttgart-Mitte</span>
        </a>
        </address>
</div>
```

Comment: [`'  text  '.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

Comment: `name.get_text().strip()`

Comment: I hade now following problem with the encoding.. : ('Abel Theophil Dr.med., Arzt für Orthopädie', 'Schwabstr.\xa091\n\n70193\xa0Stuttgart-West') there are now strings like xa091 in the middle of the street number.. the street number are not displayed.